# Reverse arguments order in curried function (ramda js)

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a higher order function: let's say for simplicity

```
const divideLeftToRight = x => y => x/y;
```

I would like to have a function that performs the division but from 'right to left'. In other words, I need to have:

```
const divideRightToLeft = x => y => y/x;
```

I thought about doing:

`const divideRightToLeft = R.curry((x,y) => divideLeftToRight(y)(x));`

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it

Comment: Don't forget you can use R.__ to not have to fudge around with getting the parameter order perfect if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for the [`flip` function](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flip):

```
const divideRightToLeft = R.flip(divideLeftToRight)
```

Comment: flip does not work with my higher order function (unless tweeking maybe).

http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20divideLeftToRight%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%20y%20%3D%3E%20x%2Fy%3B%0A%0A%0Aconst%20divideRightToLeft%20%3D%20R.flip%28divideLeftToRight%29%0A%0AdivideRightToLeft%282%29%2833%29
if my function were:
const divideLeftToRight = (x,y) => x/y;
then the flipping of arguments would work

Comment: Does `flip` work with functions curried by ramda itself (not through nested arrow functions)?

Comment: @Bergi: not exactly. It flips the first two arguments of any (arity 2+) function.  It would work fine with `(x, y) => x/y`. Or, alternately, one could use `flip` with `uncurryN`.  But it doesn't know what to do with an arity-1 function.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Can't it just assume that it is curried? `flip = f => f.length == 1 ? ((x) => (y, ...args) => f(y)(x, ...args)) : …`

Comment: @Bergi: we probably could.  It hasn't come up before that I recall, but it would make sense to do so.  We'd need something a little more complex than that, because the result should probably look like the output of other Ramda functions with several distinct ways of calling it (`fn(y)(x)`, `fn(y, x)`, but that's a detail

Answer (score 2):

You could uncurry the function before flipping. (`flip` returns a curried function.)

E.g.

```
const divideRightToLeft = R.flip(R.uncurryN(2, divideLeftToRight))
```

Alternatively, you can define a custom `flipCurried` function:

```
// https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/15f4f701ed2ba6b0d306ba7b8ca9bede223b8155/src/function.ts#L127
const flipCurried = <A, B, C>(fn: (a: A) => (b: B) => C) => (b: B) => (a: A) => fn(a)(b);

const divideRightToLeft = flipCurried(divideLeftToRight)
```